# WCF update service references breaks existing code

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a class library project being used since long time and has .NET Framework 4. It has some wcf service references (being managed by a different team) and we have one data source file "System.Xml.XmlElement.datasource" under "Properties->DataSources" which has below config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    This file is automatically generated by Visual Studio .Net. It is 
    used to store generic object data source configuration information.  
    Renaming the file extension or editing the content of this file may   
    cause the file to be unrecognizable by the program.
-->
<GenericObjectDataSource DisplayName="XmlElement" Version="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
   <TypeInfo>System.Xml.XmlElement, System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=h73c5g561921f068</TypeInfo>
</GenericObjectDataSource>
```

One of the service had some new functions, so I right clicked on the service reference, went to configure pointed to updated service url and updated the references.

Now the DataSource folder has some additional data sources files, seems to be datacontracts. And unluckily some existing data contracts are missing now. I.e. when I try to build the project I get "are you missing an assembly referece?" error in the existing logic.
However when I add the same reference to a dummy web project I am able to access all classes and types from service and build the project successfully and logics are also working fine there.

Please help me out.

Comment: Can you be a little clearer on what you mean by "broken now"?   You may need to delete the old reference and add it again.  note that if existing functionality was changed (i.e., a method signature change) or existing fields in a data contract were changed, these will be breaking changes.

Comment: @Tim : added more details. Its just I am getting missing assembly reference error for existing code. But the same service is working fine in a dummy web project.

Comment: Try removing the service reference altogether and then re-adding it.

Comment: Did same multiple time but no luck. However I got a workaround. I added reference to a separate web project and copied the Reference.cs to my project updated namespaces accordingly. And its working now.
Thank u all. But I still need to know why its not working using normal process.